# MySQL query calculated field

Tags: mysql

I would like to do this query to include the null result in another calculated field.

```
SELECT ft.fecha_inicio, 
       ft.fecha_fin, 
       IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin) fin, 
       TIMEDIFF(fin,ft.fecha_inicio) total,
       IF (ISNULL(ft.fecha_fin), 1, 0) as encurso
FROM fabricaciones_tiempos ft
WHERE ft.id_fabricacion = 138;
```

is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Output expression alias cannot be used in another output column expression. Use expression code instead of alias. PS. `IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin)` == `COALESCE( ft.fecha_fin, now() )`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use a calculated column as part of another column calculation, but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  fecha_inicio,
  fecha_fin,
  TIMEDIFF(fin,fecha_inicio) total,
  encurso
FROM (
  SELECT ft.fecha_inicio, 
       ft.fecha_fin, 
       IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin) fin, 
       IF (ISNULL(ft.fecha_fin), 1, 0) as encurso
 FROM fabricaciones_tiempos ft
 WHERE ft.id_fabricacion = 138
) as q;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the alias but you can either include the original formula in place or assign the value to a variable....

```
SELECT ft.fecha_inicio, 
       ft.fecha_fin, 
       IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin) fin, 
       TIMEDIFF(IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin),ft.fecha_inicio) total,
       IF (ISNULL(ft.fecha_fin), 1, 0) as encurso
FROM fabricaciones_tiempos ft
WHERE ft.id_fabricacion = 138;
```

or....

```
SELECT ft.fecha_inicio, 
       ft.fecha_fin, 
       @fin:=IF(ft.fecha_fin is NULL, now(), ft.fecha_fin), 
       TIMEDIFF(@fin,ft.fecha_inicio) total,
       IF (ISNULL(ft.fecha_fin), 1, 0) as encurso
FROM fabricaciones_tiempos ft
WHERE ft.id_fabricacion = 138;
```